# Is there any function that performs both tasks Ceiling and Floor itself?

Tags: c#, math

Suppose I have `2.3` , If i use `Math.Ceiling(2.3)` it will produce `3.0` and If i use `Math.Floor(2.3)` it will produce `2.0`. The question is that is there any function that perform the both tasks itself?
I mean if I use that function , it will see If digit is `less` than `.5` , it will `Floor` , otherwise use the `Ceiling` functionality !

Comment: Yes, [`Math.Round`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Math.Round(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: Exactly ! it is what i wanted.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking for `Math.Round()`.